# Should Aurelia work with traceur instead of babel?

Tags: traceur, babeljs, aurelia

I'm trying to make aurelia sample app working with traceur instead of babel. The purpose is to have static members which, as far as I understood, not supported by babebl (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/68) and learn gulp. So far I replaced babel with traceur in gulp build task, it builds, but fails in browser with various fancy errors (for example it rejects LogManager.addAppender from main.js with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addAppender' of undefined"). So before plunging into studying traceur compilation options I'd like to get opnions of seasoned ones:

Should Aurelia be able, at least theoretically,  work with traceur instead of babel?

Comment: They do work together, and if you happen to use jspm you can switch between Babel and Traceur easily. Babel does support static. Per the language spec you can only define static methods. In the issue you reference, the poster was trying to create a static field.

Comment: The compilation options aren't that complex, do you want the output to be a global object (web pages, etc., you will need to include a runtime) or module (defaults to the latter.  There are a number of experimental features also.  `traceur --out ./app.js --script /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bin/traceur-runtime.js  --script src/app.js --experimental` will build `src/app.js` as a standalone script, however you can't use module syntax with this approach. To output a CommonJS module see the `--modules` option, e.g., `traceur --dir ./src/ ./out/ --modules ... --experimental`.

Comment: ok, looks like I got it with static memebers, thank you! And although I still do not understand why traceur generates invalid LogManager.addAppender but I feel like it's not what I should investigate now  :)

Comment: and, btw, there are much more traceur options that input/output params - the traceur --longhelp outpus at least couple of dozens of lines :)